# tabOrder related to HTML table

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a table that BASICALLY looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Box 1</td>
    <td>Box 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, i have a bunch of  and  elements in both. I currently have some  elements with tabOrder=0 in Box 2. Box 1 has NO elements with tabOrder defined. The only other element in the whole file with tabOrder defined is a search box with tabOrder=-1 at a higher level above this table.

So, when this page renders, the focus is on the search box, but when i tab it still goes to the first element in Box 1, even though only elements in Box 2 have this defined! Please help. I would like the elements in Box 2 to tab first after the search box. The order after that doesn't matter. thanks!

Comment: Please add all the relevant html - the search box and whatever you have in box 1 and box 2, with the tabOrders defined, and whatever else is needed to see the problem.

Comment: the HTML is ridiculously complicated and convoluted. placing it here verbatim would just obfuscate the issue... =)
it all boils down to the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tabindex="0"` is basically the default for any input (also link?) elements.  If you want to skip over elements when pressing tab, you'll have to set `tabindex=-1` explicitly

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Comment: Ah! that make sense. i read quite a bit about that, but i never saw anything about each element having that default value, but what you're saying makes sense. i will explicitly set the Box 1 elements to tabOrder= -1. thanks!

Comment: Note that setting input elments to `tabindex=-1` means that those elements can never to tabbed to and so may make it impossible for some users to use your web page.